# How do I set datasource to my rdl reports after deployment?

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, rdl

> How do I set datasource to my rdl reports after deployment?

Currently I have created 2 different data sources for 2 different clients.

And specify that on rdl reports at the time of deployment.

But how can I do this after deployment at runtime when user clicked on `show report`

Comment: What about an rs.exe script with appropriate parameters? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162839(v=sql.120).aspx . The answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546125/change-ssrs-data-source-of-report-programmatically-in-server-side/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083951/ssrs-rdl-mapping-datasources-programmatically/ can give some ideas.

Comment: So you want a parameterized data source?

Comment: @B Woods yes but i wonder that how can I set datasource dynamically after deployment ?